# How to turn a variable into an object?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Can anyone think of a nicer solution for restructuring a variable `a` so that it becomes a plain object that contains its former value? I hate to do it like this, I'd rather prefer a one-line, but it must be still readable.

```
a = "somevalue"
b = "somekey"

tmp = a
a = {}
a[b] = tmp
```

Let me rephrase that: the desired (and from above code: the actual) result is this:

```
a = { "somekey": "somevalue" }
```

Is there a different = shorter way to achieve this when "somekey" and "somevalue" are actually variables `b`and `a`?

Comment: Why does 'a' need to be the new object? Can't you just create a new object separate from 'a'?

Comment: What you've got should work fine; you'll end up with an object referenced by "a" that's got a property called "somekey", and the value of that property will be "somevalue".

Comment: @Pointy Yeah, I know - but this is somehow a really trivial task, so I'm looking for a neat way to do this in just one line instead of three.

Comment: @Niko well you can't, without having a helper function, because the left side of the `:` in an object literal is taken to be a constant, not an expression.

Comment: You could `eval "a = {#{b}: a }"` but that's ridiculous.

Comment: @muistooshort that syntax is weird; do you mean `a = { ' + b + ':' + a + '}';` maybe?

Comment: @Pointy: CoffeeScript has Ruby-style string interpolation (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ZGR2H/). Of course, if I saw that in someone's code I'd probably consider firing them on the spot.

Comment: @muistooshort Well, that sucks because it requires eval(), but apart from that this is what I was looking for: Short and readable.

Comment: Why not just stuff those three lines into a function with a sensible name and then call that function as your one-liner? Is this really something that you want to waste more than a minute or two worrying about? Jeez, kids these days :)

Comment: Just came across this several times when reviewing code and became curious, if this can be done in a smarter way ;)

Comment: This is probably why [LiveScript](http://gkz.github.com/LiveScript/#literals) introduced object literal syntax to do just `a = {(b): a}` =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go...

```
(a = (b = [a, b, {}])[2])[b[1]] = b[0];
```

can't say I'd recommend it though.

---

Maybe this is a tiny bit better...

```
(a = (b = [a, b], {}))[b[1]] = b[0];
```

---

Certainly not shorter than what you have.

---

A little easier to read perhaps, and still getting shorter

```
(b = [a, b], a = {})[b[1]] = b[0];
```

Comment: That's even worse than my `eval` hack :)

Comment: @muistooshort: No disagreement from me. `:)` I just had to find a way to do it without a temp variable.

Comment: Interesting solution, and finally in a single statement, thanks :)

Comment: @Niko: Sure thing. Figured someone might have a little fun with it. :)

Answer (score 4):

What you have now is the way to accomplish this.

The only clean-up I can see would be to try to reduce each variable to a single purpose -- with `a` either the value or the object rather than swapping with `tmp`:

```
var k = "somekey";
var v = "somevalue";

var a = {};
a[k] = v;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `obj = (a...) -> o={}; o[a[i]]=o[a[++i]] for i in [0...a.length]; o`, than `myObject = obj key1, val1, key2, val2`?

edit: assumed you meant CoffeeScript from the tag, but its not really mentioned in the question and the rest of the answers are in JavaScript. Just for completeness sake, the JavaScript version is:

```
function obj() {
  var o={}, i, l=arguments.length;
  for (i=0; i<l; i+=2) {
    o[arguments[i]] = o[arguments[i+1]];
  }
  return o;
}

var myObject = obj(key1, val1, key2, val2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tmp = a;
a = {
    b: tmp
}
```

Comment: Sorry, b is of course a string - I've updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Please, explain it better

Answer (score 0):

Stolen from what [LiveScript](http://gkz.github.com/LiveScript) generates when with the expression `a = {(b): a}`:

```
a = "somevalue"
b = "somekey"

a = (ref = {}; ref[b] = a; ref)
```

It still needs an auxiliar variable, but it's quite readable IMO and now it's a one-liner =D

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't know LiveScript very well and didn't know it was a fork of Coco... your comment got me looking into it tho, and its pretty neat. thanks :-)

Comment: @shesek Yeap. I really like how these CoffeeScript-derived projects kinda work as incubators for new ideas for CS itself. In the case of this extended object literal notation, i think it's quite a nice addition that could work well in CS :)